# $\sigma$-algebra generated by analytic sets

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

The Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\cal B$ on real numbers has many good properties. For instance, all continuous functions are $\cal B/\cal B$-measurable. On the other side, not only $\cal B$ is not complete but, as discovered by Suslin, $\cal B$ is not closed under *images* of continuous functions.

It is tempting then to consider the $\sigma$-algebra, say ${\cal B}^1$, generated by [analytic sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set), or even, going up along the [projective hierachy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy), to consider the $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal B}^{\infty}$ generated by projective sets.

It would by nice to know if these $\sigma$-algebra share some properties with the Borel one that make $\cal B$ useful.

> **Question I:** Are continuous functions ${\cal B}^1/ {\cal B}^1$-measurable?

Comment: Similarly to Gerald's answer for analytic sets, one can show that $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_n$ sets are closed under continuous (even Borel) preimages, so that continuous functions are $\mathcal B^n/\mathcal B^n$ measurable.

Comment: The following result might also be of interest: for a function $f$ between Polish spaces the following are equivalent, where $\Gamma$-measurable for a pointclass $\Gamma$ means that the preimages of open sets are in $\Gamma$: 1. $f$ is $\mathbf{\Delta}^1_n$-measurable 2. $f$ is $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_n$-measurable 3. $f$ is $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_n$-measurable 4. the graph of $f$ is $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_n$ 5. the graph of $f$ is $\mathbf{\Delta}^1_n$. (at the $n=1$ level this says that a function is Borel iff its graph is Borel iff its graph is analytic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Inverse image of an analytic set is analytic" would imply ${\cal B}^1/ {\cal B}^1$-measurable, so let's try that.  [Check my argument.]

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous.  Let $B \subseteq \mathbb R$ be an analytic set.  Write $A = f^{-1}(B)$.  We want to show that $A$ is analytic.

Let $\pi_1, \pi_2: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be the projections onto the coordinates: $\pi_1(x,y) = x, \pi_2(x,y) = y$.  There is a Borel set $C \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ such that $\pi_1(C) = B$.

Define $F : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ by $F(x,y) = (f(x),y)$.
So $F$ is continuous. Let $D = F^{-1}(C)$.  So $D$ is a Borel set.

\begin{align}
x \in \pi_1(D) &\Longleftrightarrow
\exists y, (x,y) \in D 
\\&\Longleftrightarrow
\exists y, (x,y) \in F^{-1}(C) 
\\&\Longleftrightarrow
\exists y, F(x,y) \in C 
\\&\Longleftrightarrow
\exists y, (f(x),y) \in C 
\\&\Longleftrightarrow
\exists y, \pi_1(f(x),y) \in B 
\\&\Longleftrightarrow
f(x) \in B 
\\&\Longleftrightarrow
x \in f^{-1}(B) 
\\&\Longleftrightarrow
x \in A 
\end{align}

That is, $A = \pi_1(D)$.  So $A$ is an analytic set.

Comment: Thank you! I also add the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917026/every-analytic-subset-of-bbbr-is-the-projection-of-a-g-delta-set-g-sub) as a comment as further details.